# multiple css backgrounds not working

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to use 3 backgrounds on a div like so.

```
.leftcontent
{
    padding: 0 20px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    width: 615px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    background:
        url('../images/primary_content_bottom_item31.gif') bottom left no-repeat,
        url('../images/primary_content_bg.gif') repeat-y,
        url('../images/primary_content_bg2.gif') top left no-repeat;
}
.left
{
    float: left;
}
```

The problem is that `primary_content_bg2.gif` background image does not display.

However it does display when I remove the first 2 backgrounds (`primary_content_bottom_item31.gif` and `primary_content_bg.gif`).

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class='left leftcontent'>
    <h1>Lottery</h1>
    <p>The Brookvale Lottery was set up in 1976 to help raise money for the building of our Village Hall. Today, the lottery raises funds for the day to day running and upkeep of the Hall. In 2012, as well as paying out to Brookvale residents, it also paid for the purchase and installation of security fencing at the Hall.</p>
    <p>The Lottery is open to all residents of Brookvale over 16.</p>
    <h2 class=center><strong>1st Prize - &pound;50</strong></h2>
    <h2 class=center><strong>2nd Prize - &pound;30</strong></h2>
    <h2 class=center><strong>3rd Prize - &pound;20</strong></h2>
    <p>To find out how the lottery works, see Rules of Play.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/98417tvj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second defined background is displayed above the last one. This should work:

```
background:
    url('../images/primary_content_bottom_item31.gif') bottom left no-repeat,
    url('../images/primary_content_bg2.gif') top left no-repeat,
    url('../images/primary_content_bg.gif') repeat-y;
```

The order of defining images is the order of their displaying. The earlier defined are displayed above the later defined.